# Swift where to place code in viewcontrolles

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

As a newbie on iOS dev with swift I wanna ask where I should put code in view controllers. If it even matters.

By that I mean, should custom functions() and variables come before the standard eg override functions() ?

Also,

Can I delete:

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

From files that I dont use it in at all?

Comment: You can. If you don't want to monitor memory warnings in your app.

Comment: Same as Objective-C: if you need to override existing methods, do that. If you want to add your own methods, you can do that too.

Comment: The order of variables and functions is totally up to you as long as it is inside a class or struct. There are no rules to placement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a method that needs `override` like `viewWillAppear` than it's as simple as

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

}
```

If you want just a normal function, maybe with a parameter, you can do it like this

```
func myNewFunction(name: String) {}
```

This gives me a new function that takes in a string. It can appear at the top scope right next to viewDidLoad, your inits, etc.

My variables go at the top. I put them like so

```
// MARK: - Outlets
[my Outlets from Storyboard]

// MARK: - Class Properties
[my constants]

[my variables]

// MARK: - Initializers
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder {
     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

// MARK: - View Handlers
[viewDidLoad and didRecieveMemoryWarning, etc...]

// MARK: - Utility Methods

[all my functions]

[[end of class]]
```

As for your `didRecieveMemoryWarning` you can delete it but I recommend you keep in your view controller in case you want to manage memory.

Comment: Thanks, and is there any problem with having too much code in the VC? Beside readability

Comment: I would say as long as it's relevant to the view controller, it's fine; there's no size limit :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete `didReceiveMemoryWarning`

Code you want to run when you start a viewcontroller should be placed in

```
override public func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // your code here....
}
```

It good practice to place instance variables at the top of you class.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned to put instance variables all the way at the top, but also seen variables that existed below functions. I also grouped `override` in their own cluster, and grouped my custom functions in another. Extensions is a good way to group a set of functions.

Yes, you can delete `didReceiveMemoryWarning` since the super implementation will always exist.